# How can I use a Pretrained TF model in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I have a tensorflow based image classification model which I want to import in ML studio and deploy through it. 
I am unable to find a way to import a frozen model.

Can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a trained model, you should rather make use of the Azure Machine Learning Service, not ML Studio. Here is a tutorial how to register and deploy your model with the ML service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a good idea... Do you also have any used case example.

Comment: Have you looked at the walk through in the linked documentation? Or what are you missing?